# Updating material ui select options from input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I'm new to Reactjs, here i have material ui select element, as you can see i have default values for select element, and also by clicking 'ADD USER' button and submitting, i can add new values to select element, and from select element i can also delete options, my question here is how can i edit specific option from select element, i have added EditUser component for that when option is clicked, but dont know how to update it, any advice ?

my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-ysglz8?file=/src/AddUser.js

App.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import { MenuProps, useStyles } from "./utils";
import AddUser from "./AddUser";
import {
  Button,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent
} from "@material-ui/core";
import EditUser from "./EditUser";

function App() {
  const rawOptions = [
    "Oliver Hansen",
    "Van Henry",
    "April Tucker",
    "Ralph Hubbard",
    "Omar Alexander",
    "Carlos Abbott",
    "Miriam Wagner",
    "Bradley Wilkerson",
    "Virginia Andrews",
    "Kelly Snyder"
  ];

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(rawOptions);
  const [openAddModal, setOpenAddModal] = useState(false);
  const [openUpdateModal, setOpenUpdateModal] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("vals", event.target);
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
    console.log("values", selected);
  };

  function addUser(newArray) {
    setOptions(newArray);
  }

  const openAddUser = () => {
    setOpenAddModal(true);
  };
  const openUpdateUser = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    setOpenUpdateModal(true);
  };

  const closeAddModal = () => {
    setOpenAddModal(false);
  };
  const closeUpdateModal = () => {
    setOpenUpdateModal(false);
  };

  const updateUser = (updateUser) => {
    setOptions(updateUser);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <div>
        <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="mutiple-select-label"
          multiple
          variant="outlined"
          value={selected || []}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) => selected}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {options.map((option, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox checked={selected?.includes(option)} />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={option.title}>{option}</ListItemText>
              <DeleteIcon
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.stopPropagation();
                  setOptions(options.filter((o) => o !== option));
                  console.log("run");
                }}
              />
              <ListItemIcon>
                <CreateIcon onClick={openUpdateUser} />
              </ListItemIcon>
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
        <Button onClick={openAddUser} style={{ backgroundColor: "#287B7A" }}>
          Add User
        </Button>
      </div>
      <p>{selected}</p>

      <AddUser
        openAddModal={openAddModal}
        handleClose={closeAddModal}
        array={options}
        addUser={addUser}
      />

      <EditUser
        openUpdateModal={openUpdateModal}
        handleClose={closeUpdateModal}
        array={options}
        updateUser={updateUser}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your users haven't any ids or something that they can be identified with.

Try to make users array of objects like this

```
const rawOptions = [
   {
     id: 0,
     name: "Oliver Hansen"

   },
  ];
```

Make your inputs and etc. accept array of objects.

After this in your Edit component, you should pass there selected user object and set default state for your input value (so your can really edit it and not input a new value)
`const [value, setValue] = useState(props.user.name);`

And in your `someFunction`, that acts like handleSubmit function, pass your user object, or user id and new value. It will look like

```
const someFunction = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (value) {
       props.hanldeSubmit(props.user.id, value)
       props.handleClose() // Might be better to put it into your handleSubmit in parent component
    }

  };
```

And finally in your `App.js`, create handleSubmit function that accepts user id and value, and modify your state in it. Find user by ID and put a new value.
Do not forget to pass this function into your EditUser component.

Hope that helped you!

**UPDATE**

Ooookay, so, you might also want to start with less hard examples, but lets stick to what we have. I'll note here some problems that I found, and explain how to make it work.

First of all, always name functions and variables correctly, you should understand what function or variable do only by its name (ideally), I understand that this is just an example code and etc, but this makes this point only more important, because when you learn something new, its good not to make it harder for yourself.

Second thing, just for some case, I don't know if this mistake or not, so I mention this:

```
<CreateIcon
   onClick={() =>
      openUpdateUser({ id: option.id, name: option.name })
   }
/>
```

Here you pass object, and in openUpdateUser you accept e (event) as a first parameter. Just for you to know, you will get event in your anonymous function and it wouldn't be passed further in openUpdateUser, to pass it, you should write it like this:

```
<CreateIcon
   onClick={(e) =>
      openUpdateUser(e, { id: option.id, name: option.name })
   }
/>
```

**Okay, let's get back to business.**

The first real problem here: You have your options in one state, and selected options in other, so when you add some user, you will see users from `selected`. What problem does it cause? When you will try to update user in your options, it might be updated, but you wouldn't see any changes in selected, because it two different states.

We will solve it by making one source of information. Now we will store in selected not users, but users ids and in render we will get users from our options by ids.

```
// before
<p>{selected}</p>

// after
{selected.map(selectedUserId => (
  <div>{options.filter(option => option.id === selectedUserId)[0].name}</div>
))}
```

Now, any changes to options will affect your selected users. Also, update your code to add\remove ids and not user objects.

Let's go further, now you have your selected user and method for updating in edit component, let's go edit:

```
// EditUser.js
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.edit.name); // set user name as default value to edit it
  function changeValue(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const someFunction = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (value) {
       props.updateUser({id: props.edit.id, name: value}) // Pass user id and new value to our update function
       props.handleClose();
    }
    
  };
```

So, now we have our new value in update function, the only one thing left is to save those updates. We'll do it in easy way:

```
// Normally here would be some api call for user update
const updateUser = (updateUser) => {
  const temp = [...options] // Not deep copy of our options
  temp[temp.findIndex(user => user.id === updateUser.id)].name = updateUser.name;
  setOptions(temp) 
};
```

And thats all, now it should work as expected.
Also as improve, you can restructure your options array of objects to make it easier to modify data.
(yep, I know that it was my suggestion, but anyway :) )
Currently it looks like this:

```
const rawOptions = [
   {
     id: 0,
     name: "Oliver Hansen"

   },
  ];
```

We can make it object of objects, where key will be id of user:

```
const rawOptions = {
   0: {
     id: 0,
     name: "Oliver Hansen"

   },
  };
```

```
//Now to get user you can just do 
options[userId]
// To get users array 
Object.values(options)
// To modify user 
const updateUser = (updateUser) => {
  setOptions({...options}, [updateUser.id]: updateUser) 
};
```

Just like previously, I wouldn't make those changes into codesandbox, the best way to learn programming is to write some code by yourself :)

If you will find any other issues or questions, feel free to ask, hope it helps :)

Comment: could you possibly give working example so i can accept ?

Comment: It actually requires a refactor of most part of your code on codesandbox, and I'm currently working, so sorry, but no. You can try to do it yourself, and if you will struggle with some bug then just provide another link to codesandbox with updated code and I will take a look at it. I believe that most of that work (or even all of it), you are able to do by yourself :)

Comment: ok i did as you said, added id's to those and also when adding new user it generates id to it, but still dont know how to edit here : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-6mzi50?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Made an update for you :)

Comment: @O   i got it working but few questions: 1) when i select something (by clicking its checkbox), then i delete that same(by clicking recycle bin), it gets deleted but i can still see it on select element (not in dropdown)   2)  when i edit some of those (by clicking pencil) then edit dialog appears but behind dropdown (how can i make dropdown go away after clicked edit ?) https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-ipukpk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: 1. You haven't did it like I said, you still add user name to `selected`. And your delete method looking for id, but you got no ids in `selected` array. You can modify your edit and delete method or make it my way.

2. You have states that control visibility of your popups, so just hide dropdown popup when edit button is clicked. 

You should more often console.log and check what you have in different states, that will provide you more information about what you have and what is going on in your code